# crontab every minute, but after script at boot up

Tags: cron

I have a question regarding crontab. I have a script which I start after boot. The script needs sometimes more or less time. The problem is I want to use a script every minute but only if the script at the boot was successful. Because sometimes it isn't and than it auto reboots the raspberry and it tries it again. The problem is that the script at boot is necessary for the crontab script. Is there a better way than putting a sleep in the crontab file or the script?

Many thanks

Cheers Max

Comment: Have your start script writing its pid in some `/var/run/mystart.pid` file, removing that file at script exit. Test existence of that script in the periodic script.

Comment: can you not set an ENVIRONMENT variable to something and check if this is the value, it was a successful/unsuccessful run.

Comment: I didn't know about this way to create a script at boot up, I just added one command line to the .bashrc of my special user

Comment: @hagubear, that's a good idea, maybe some kind of global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the boot script create a file. The cron job should look for the file, and exit if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I know you don't do that, I'm telling you to change the script to do it.

Comment: okay so I misunderstood you! But I am using a sd card in read-only mode to avoid a data error in case of a power failure. So I gonna use a global variable. I just thought maybe there is a way to do this in the crontab file and avoid to change to much other files/scripts.